# Cannot convert string to buffer. toBuffer only supports 0x-prefixed hex strings

Tags: ethereumjs

Getting error while creating ethereum raw transaction

```
var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x2a',
  gasPrice: '0x4a717c800',
  gasLimit: '0xc340',
  to: '0x73F7Ced8cc9D27DC426210c32fc6d0a40f941eE1',
  value: '0x2386f26fc10000',
  data: '',
  chainID: 4 
}      
var cTx = await new EthereumTx(rawTx, { 'chain': 'rinkeby' });
cTx.sign(privateKeyInBuffer);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try change data :'' to data:"0x"

Comment: why does this work?

Answer (score 4):

ethereum-utils checks string fields if they are hex. When you send data field as empty, then it throws the error. You can send data as '0x' like they said above.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `privateKey` with `Buffer.from(privateKey.slice(2), "hex")`.

Comment: i am already using privatekey in buffer

Comment: @IshwarChandra: Did this method not work for you? If yes, then please elaborate on what error it gives you.

Comment: i have used your given solution but i am still getting same error

Answer (score 2):

This might be happening, because you are trying to sign the raw transaction with private key in string format, but it has to be hex. Change:

`cTx.sign(privateKey)`

To:

`cTx.sign(new Buffer(privateKey, 'hex'))`

And on a side note, here `var cTx = await new EthereumTx(rawTx, { 'chain': 'rinkeby' });` you don't have to pass chain parameter, you already specified to which blockchain network the transaction should be sent in `rawTx` where you placed this parameter `chainID: 4`. Full list with blockchain networks can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md#list-of-chain-ids).

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution**

```
 var rawTx = {
      nonce: '0x2a',
      gasPrice: '0x4a717c800',
      gasLimit: '0xc340',
      to: '0x73F7Ced8cc9D27DC426210c32fc6d0a40f941eE1',
      value: '0x2386f26fc10000',
      data: '0x',=====================>>**change empty data string to 0x**
      chainID: 4 
    }
```