# @ethereumjs/tx: toBuffer only supports 0x-prefixed hex strings

Tags: ethereumjs

N.B.: I have seen [this Stack Exchange question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80205/cannot-convert-string-to-buffer-tobuffer-only-supports-0x-prefixed-hex-strings),
and its solutions do not work.

I am trying to deploy a contract on Goerli but am getting the following error:

```
throw new Error(`Cannot convert string to buffer. toBuffer 
only supports 0x-prefixed hex strings and this string was 
given: ${v}`);

Error: Cannot convert string to buffer. toBuffer only 
supports 0x-prefixed hex strings and this string was given: 
0x60806...
000...0002F
    at toBuffer (/home/kevin/coding/dao-voting/besu-deploy/node_modules/@ethereumjs/util/dist/bytes.js:147:19)
    at new BaseTransaction (/home/kevin/coding/dao-voting/besu-deploy/node_modules/@ethereumjs/tx/dist/baseTransaction.js:53:41)
    at new Transaction (/home/kevin/coding/dao-voting/besu-deploy/node_modules/@ethereumjs/tx/dist/legacyTransaction.js:28:9)
    at main (/home/kevin/coding/dao-voting/besu-deploy/public_tx.js:35:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.7.0
```

This happens when I try to do the following:

```js
const rawTxOptions = {
  nonce: web3.utils.numberToHex(txnCount),
  from: account.address,
  to: null, //public tx
  value: "0x00",
  data: '0x'+contractBin+contractConstructorInit, // contract binary appended with initialization value
  gasPrice: "0x0", //ETH per unit of gas
  gasLimit: "0x24A22" //max number of gas units the tx is allowed to use
};
const tx = new Tx(rawTxOptions);
```

I know the string that's giving the error is from the `data`
field since it matches `'0x'+contractBin` (`contractBin`
from [this
file](https://github.com/Kevin-Mok/besu-deploy/blob/main/SimpleStorage.bin)).
So as can be seen in the error, the `data` and string given
does start with `0x`. So, why am I getting this error?
I have created a [simple
repository](https://github.com/Kevin-Mok/besu-deploy) to
reproduce this error along with [steps to run
it](https://github.com/Kevin-Mok/besu-deploy#running).

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer in [my @ethereumjs/tx issue](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/issues/2606#issuecomment-1487330116):

> The issue seems to be in how you are constructing the transaction data field. In your sample repo, you are concatenating `data: '0x'+contractBin+contractConstructorInit` where `contractBin` is a `buffer` and not a string. If you replace this with `data: '0x'+contractBin.toString('hex')+contractConstructorInit`, this error should go away.